# How to decrypt original password after hash token expires

Tags: php, security, encryption, hash

I'm building a REST API in PHP and I'm currently working on the security side of things.

I have read a lot about network authentication and implemented some suggested strategies.

I'll explain what I've done so far and where I got stuck.

To prevent a hacker from knowing all users' passwords if they got their hands on my database, I keep only a hashed version of the passwords in db. I use the php password_hash() function that creates a salt automatically. Also, the hashed password expires 30 minutes after logging in with the original password.

To prevent sniffers from seeing the hashed password in request headers, the client sends several headers in every request: a timestamp, some random string and a hashed checksum of the combination of hash+timestamp+random_string+url.

Now, my question is what happens when the hash token expires (after 30 minutes)? The user now needs to send their original password to get a new token, but the server only keeps a hash of the original password. Using the checksum method wouldn't work because the server needs the original password to get the right result for hash comparison. So it has no way of knowing the user password is correct.

P.S. I'm not worried about replay attacks at the moment, but if I were to implement security against this kind of attack, would I have to keep a history of all Nonce strings at the client side and all cNonce strings at the server side?

Thank you.

EDIT:

The documentation states that password_hash() uses bcrypt algorithm which handles the creation of a salt automatically.
As for the checksum string, I hash it using the SHA256 algorithm.

Comment: hashes are ***one way*** and you can't "decrypt" passwords when they're hashed.

Comment: Let's use this analogy: It's like trying to use ground/hashed meat and wanting to make it look like a Black Angus again ;-)

Comment: You may be over-thinking this just a *tad*. Is this level of complexity justified for what you're trying to protect?

Comment: @Fred-ii- ok maybe I "mistitled" my issue. I'm aware you can't unhash a hash. My problem is allowing the server to get the same hash result from user input: hash(plain_text_password+timestamp+random_string+url). The server must know the plain text password in order to get the same combined hash result.

Comment: that would depend on which algo was used to hash it. I've read somewhere that some algos can generate the same hash, before salting. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php they talk about it in there.

Comment: The documentation says the default algorithm for password_hash() is the "bcrypt blowfish". Also, the documentation states: "The used algorithm, cost and salt are returned as part of the hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it. This allows the password_verify() function to verify the hash without needing separate storage for the salt or algorithm information."

Comment: @JayBlanchard For this specific project it may not be justified but I want to build a template for future projects that require this level of security. I realize that keeping the original password in the db would solve my problem but is it what most developers do?

Comment: Yes, the original hash stays in the database. We typically use the hash + date + other things to give the user a token. The token expires, not the hash.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, my question is what happens when the hash token expires (after 30
>   minutes)? The user now needs to send their original password to get a
>   new token, but the server only keeps a hash of the original password.

Simply use the [`password-verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) function to validate the plaintext password sent to you by the client matches your stored hash in your database.

- `$password` is the user supplied password (not a hash).
- `$hash` is the password hash stored in the user's database record, containing the algorithm, salt and hash.

Complexity is the enemy of security. Keep things as simple as possible. Ensure your connection is over HTTPS - this will encrypt and verify the password data in transit and HTTPS uses TLS/SSL which also prevents replay attacks.

Comment: Yea well, I wanted to avoid using https. I'm looking for a strategy to send the plain_text_password in normal http connection in a way no one could decipher it and still not have to store the plain_text_password in the database. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Not possible, unless you're a professional cryptographer and you have 10 years spare to perfect your algorithm. Then you'd just end up designing https.